# blocking socket client example

Tags: python

i need to connect to a blocking service using tcp ports (if someone here knows about it, it is a motorola digital wirelink protocol service) , i need a good starting point example, ideally in perl, python or php which are the languages i know better.

So far i have tried this basic example with no luck.

```
import socket
import sys

HOST, PORT = "172.16.10.5", 15142
data = " ".join(sys.argv[1:])

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
print "connected"

sock.send(data + "\n")
print "data sent"

received = sock.recv(1024)
print "data received"
sock.close()

print "Sent:     %s" % data
print "Received: %s" % received
```

the script just hangs forever after sock.send 
do anyone of you know of a good example?
regards

Answer (score 2):

You probably need \r\n instead of \n.  If you don't terminate properly, a response won't be sent.

Comment: i change it to "\r\n", but same result... :-(

Comment: If it is hanging, the data being sent is not correct.  It is waiting for a complete command.  Check the protocol and make sure you are following it exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about this specific protocol, but instead of managing sockets yourself, I would have to recommend the [Twisted framework](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) for networking in Python.

> Twisted is an event-driven networking engine written in Python and licensed under the MIT license.

Comment: i have looked at the twisted framework, but i think (by reading the docs) it is for asyncronous non-blocking sockets, i need it syncronous blocking.